# Combining lists and deleting duplicates based on specific column

Tags: python-3.x, list, merge, duplicates

I have three lists, call them list1, list2 and list3. I need to combine these lists and delete duplicates based on the first column. Any ideas?

For example;

```
list1   list2   list3
  A       12     USA
  B       14     USA
  A       16     Cuba

What I need is:

list1   list2   list3
  A       12     USA
  B       14     USA
```

Comment: is this with `Pandas` output?

Comment: All of them are list and I need them as list at the end as well.

Comment: okay, there is duplicate `USA`, any idea?

Comment: I only want to get rid of the duplicates in the first list, list1, but the rest should be modified as well.